# Recursing through object to check for undefined values

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to put together a utility function that will look at the values of keys [?] in an object and detect when any are undefined.
The aim is to sanity-check the object against 'row' which is returned from a database query - if the column doesn't exist in the database then I need to flag this up.
After some searching here, I have the following:

```
...
{
    const newEv: myEventType = {
        position: { lat: row.LatV, lng: row.LongV },
        txt: row.Text
    }

    const undef: string = CheckUndefined(newEv, "myEventType")
}


function CheckUndefined(ev: object, evName: string): string {

    let exc: string = ""

    const keys = Object.keys(ev)

    keys.map(key => {
        if (Reflect.get(ev, key) === undefined) {
            if (exc.length == 0) {
                // TODO Not have to pass 'evName' to this function
                exc = `Undefined fields in ${evName}:`
            }
            exc += " " + `'${key}'`
        }

        // else if ....
        // TODO Determine if the key is itself an object, in which case recurse into it too

        else
            console.log(`Good, ${key} is indeed defined`)
    })

    return exc
}
```

(There may be slicker ways?, but that's what my reading came up with)

This works, but I'd like to enhance further (see the TODOs):
1. Importantly, a key may be an object itself (e.g. 'position'), in which case I'd like to recurse into that and check it too.
2. Ideally, not have to pass 'evName' to the function - have CheckUndefined detect it automatically from 'ev')

Any help/improvements gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: I don't think detecting evName automatically from ev is at all possible. TypeScript is basically JavaScript with compile-time type checking. There's no run-time type info in JavaScript.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks  - I did have a sense that 'reverse transpile' might not be possible. That aspect was just to put extra error info into the exception message - it's not a crucial bit